# How to print all nested object properties name

Tags: c#, types, properties

I am trying to print all the properties name from an object including all the properties name of it's child objects, for example

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
public class Subject
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ScoreCalculator ScoreCalculator { get; set; }
}
public class ScoreCalculator
{
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public bool Pass { get; set; }
}
```

Student is parent object.

Subject is child object of Student.

ScoreCalculator is child object of Subject.

What I expected to see

```
Id
Code
Score
Pass
```

I tried below method. It can print parent properties name only.

```
public static void PrintAllPropertiesNames<T>(T parentObject, int remainingLayersToGo = 3)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor eachPropertyDescriptor in propertyDescriptorCollection)
    {
        Type type = eachPropertyDescriptor.PropertyType;

        //if(remainingLayersToGo > 0 && type is IEnumerable || type is Object) <- @I was trying to recognize data type.
        if (remainingLayersToGo > 0 && false)
        {
            var childObject = eachPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(parentObject);
            PrintAllPropertiesNames(childObject, remainingLayersToGo--);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(eachPropertyDescriptor.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

@This is incorrect. I don't know how to recognize for object(Subject,ScoreCalculator), enumerations(array,list) and normal data type (string, int & double)

Comment: How deep do you want this to go? Assuming you implement this correctly, what if `Subject` has a `List<Student> EnrolledStudents` property, for example? Now, you'll be going back and forth between the properties of `Student` and the properties of `Subject` in an endless loop or until the stack is full.

Comment: Have you considered creating something like a `GetStudentInfo` property in the `Student` class that would return a `string` with the student id and all the subjects as you describe?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Yes, you are right. Thanks! I should set a limit

Comment: @JohnG Thanks! But actually those `Object` are not under my control. I only know they have some properties. In big picture , I would like to create a generic method to convert those nested objects to `DataTable`. Therefore, I need to query all properites name for create `DataColumn`.

Comment: I think the right technique needed here is reflection.  To familiarize yourself with the topic, I can recommend [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection.)  In the Related sections, there is something specifically about a generic implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think reflection is the tool of choice for this problem. With reflection it is possible to examine every little detail of an object. The difficulty is rather examining the right details of an object that lead to the desired goal.  And to find the right functionality for it.
The basis for the following example is the source code from your question.

**NOTE: The following example is really not in good programming style, it is simply intended to show an approach to inspecting objects with reflection.**

First I provided the corresponding classes with constructors so that the dependencies for the entire object are created.

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        var subject1 = new Subject();
        List<Subject> Subjects = new List<Subject>();
        Subjects.Add(subject1);
    }
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public Subject()
    {
        ScoreCalculator = new ScoreCalculator();
    }
        
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ScoreCalculator ScoreCalculator { get; set; }
}

public class ScoreCalculator
{
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public bool Pass { get; set; }
}
```

Next, the object is created and passed to the method.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var student = new Student();
    PrintAllPropertiesNames(student);
}
```

The method shows only a fraction of the possibilities that are available.  But it shows an approach how you could examine your objects.

```
public static void PrintAllPropertiesNames<T>(T obj)
{
    if(obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
            
    var objType = obj.GetType();
    Console.WriteLine($"{objType.Name} Properties:");
            
    var objProperties = objType.GetProperties();
    foreach(var property in objProperties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"    + {property.Name}");
    }
            
    var propertySubjects = objType.GetProperty("Subjects");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"{propertySubjects.Name} Info:");
    Console.WriteLine($"    + Type: {propertySubjects.PropertyType}");
            
    var subjectsArguments = propertySubjects.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
    foreach(var argument in subjectsArguments)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"    + Generic Argument: {argument.Name}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
            
    var subjectType = subjectsArguments[0];
    var subjectProperties = subjectType.GetProperties();
    Console.WriteLine($"{subjectType.Name} Properties:");
    foreach(var property in subjectProperties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"    + {property.Name}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
            
    var scoreCalculater = subjectType.GetProperty("ScoreCalculator");
    Console.WriteLine($"{scoreCalculater.Name} Properties:");
    var scoreCalculatorProperties = scoreCalculater.PropertyType.GetProperties();
    foreach(var property in scoreCalculatorProperties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"    + {property.Name}");
    }
}
```

The example produces the following output.

```
Student Properties:
    + Id
    + Subjects

Subjects Info:
    + Type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HelloWold.Subject]
    + Generic Argument: Subject

Subject Properties:
    + Code
    + ScoreCalculator

ScoreCalculator Properties:
    + Score
    + Pass
```

I can recommend the MSDN to go deeper into the topic:
[Reflection inC#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)

I hope I could help you with this.